# mongodb upsert from java: how to get _id of existing object?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I'm using the mongo-jackson-wrapper with java and MongoDB. I find an object by querying a field of mine (not the _id field), and then I need to know the _id field value, whether
the net result was an update or an insert. However, I get an exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: No objects to return
    at net.vz.mongodb.jackson.WriteResult.getSavedId(WriteResult.java:97)
```

The exception comes from the wrapper, not the MongoDB driver itself.

```
WriteResult<EntityDocument, String> wr 
   = coll.update(DBQuery.is("corefEntityId", corefEntityId), up, true,  false);
```

What (if anything) is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **findAndModify** and set *returnNew* to *true*

You can view the [JavaDoc](http://vznet.github.io/mongo-jackson-mapper/apidocs/net/vz/mongodb/jackson/JacksonDBCollection.html#findAndModify%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

This code should do the trick but I haven't tested it.

`coll.findAndModify(DBQuery.is("corefEntityId", corefEntityId), null, null, false, up, true,  false);`